# Marketing as Christian products

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah

I am selling posters with pasukim on them on Amazon. Many people are searching for "Christian Posters" if I put this keyword in the title of my listing, it helps with ranking for those searches. However is this seen as selling for Avodah Zara or any other issue? All the pasukim are from the tanakh of course. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MY. Thank you for your question. If your asking for a psak halacha you should probably call a competent rabbi. From my little understanding, there might be a problem of selling things directly to be used for avodah zara since your marketing it as such. Just a thought.

Comment: As far as I know, the *issur* of *lipheihem ve'lo liphnei...* does not apply to *Torah she'bichsav* so this is *mutar*.

Comment: https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040308030457W-34%20Contemporary%20Avodah%20Zara%20Issues.pdf
At the end of the article they mention Rav Belsky who says it's not recommended to sell holiday lights. Perhaps this is different, I have no idea what they use these posters for.

Comment: Would you knowingly sell your poster to a Christian? If so, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Depending on how your set up on Amazon, you might be able to consider them as the sellers and your selling it to Amazon. In that case it's a lot easier with this issue since they're a reseller not the end user. Your just advertising to people that Amazon is selling this (indirectly benefiting you, but your not the seller direct). Again, AYLOR.

Comment: @BenZand - This marketing decision is ironic since the mitsvah to help souls develop their relationship with HaShem by teaching Torah through posters would be diminished by associating false keywords with products to benefit sales. - Similar to Christian Marketing of the New Testament.

Comment: It is still *false advertising* as it would be like implying that this validates the avodas zarah.

Comment: @sabbahillel How is it false advertising? Christians accept the Tanakh as written. I buy accurate, especially Jewish translations of the Hebrew Bible and give them to Christian friends and in laws and they always appreciate and accept them.

Comment: I have asked a rav and he says as long as the pasukim are from the tanakh, it's fine.

Comment: Actually they do not. They put their spin and mistranslation into it. For example, the *virgin* mistranslation that they use to pretend that their deity was born. While it may appear to be accurate, they do put their own spin on it.